# Returning a Generic Interface - can't cast return type if sealed

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

I have the following interface and abstract types:

```
public interface IByteSerializer<T> {...}

public abstract class ByteSerializer<T> : IByteSerializer<T> {...}

public sealed class UIDSerializer : ByteSerializer<UID> {...}
```

And I want to be able to return an interface using the static generic method below:

```
public abstract class SerializableObject<T> : IByteSerializable<T>
{
    // ...

    public static IByteSerializer<T> GetTypeSerializer()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(UID)) { return new UIDSerializer() as IByteSerializer<T>; }

        // else if...

        throw new TypeAccessException("An IByteSerializer does not exist for type " + typeof(T) + ".");
    }
}
```

Why can't I simply `return new UIDSerializer();`?  Attempting to do so fails with the error:

`CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type UIDSerializer to IByteSerializer<T>`

The only way I have been able to get this to work is using the `as` operator, as above - which does work. However an explicit `(cast)` also fails. If I try:

`return (IByteSerializer<T>)new UIDSerializer();`

I get both a `cannot convert type` error and a `cast is redundant` warning.  These seem to totally contradict eachother!

Where is the lapse in my thinking?

**UPDATE:**

Removing the `sealed` modifier from the `UIDSerializer` class allows me to successfully cast the return type to `IByteSerializer<T>`. So what does this modifier have to do with the cast?

```
public class UIDSerializer : ByteSerializer<UID> {...} // not sealed
```

allows

```
return (IByteSerializer<T>)new UIDSerializer();
```

Comment: Can you at least provide code that compiles? e.g. What is `IByteSerializable`?

Comment: Two things are going on. First, see marked duplicate for why the compiler can't trust that a cast is valid (addresses your failed attempt to cast explicitly). Second, `UIDSerializer` doesn't implement `IByteSerializable<T>`, it implements `IByteSerializable<UID>`. The return value has to work for _all_ `T`, not just `UID`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho except `UIDSerializer` *does* implement `IByteSerializer<T>` via the abstract class `ByteSerializer<UID>` ?

Comment: @DavidG I think it's unrelated to the question.

Comment: I wonder if changing the interface to be `IByteSerializer<out T>` would fix it?

Comment: @itsme86 `Invalid variance modifier. Only interface and delegate type parameters can be specified as variant.`

Comment: Did you accidentally do it on `ByteSerializer` instead of `IByteSerializer`?

Comment: _"UIDSerializer does implement IByteSerializer<T>"_ -- **no, it does not.** As I already explained in my prevoous comment, it implements `IByteSerializer<UID>`. That is _not_ the same type as `IByteSerializer<T>`. Suppose someone calls `SerializableObject<int>.GetTypeSerializer()`. What type is that method going to return? I hope you understand it will be `IByteSerializer<int>`. If the compiler were to allow you to return `IByteSerializer<UID>`, what is a caller that expects `IByteSerializer<int>` supposed to do with that?

Comment: The bottom line here is that if you find yourself explicitly checking `typeof(T)` in a generic class or method, you've probably screwed up the design somewhere along the way. There's not enough context in your code to understand exactly what you did wrong, but the compiler is helping you avoid at least the worst consequences of your mistake here. The errors are correct, and well-understood by most.

Comment: @khargoosh It doesn't matter if it's related or not. If someone can't come along ang copy/paste your code into a test project and run it, they will get stuck or give up. Help people to help you...

Comment: @PeterDuniho thank you, that helps me understand my mistake.  I admit in the question that the lapse is in my thinking of course.  This method is meant to be a factory type method, does your `typeof(T)` remark still apply?

Comment: _"factory type method, does your typeof(T) remark still apply?"_ -- in general, I'd say yes, still applies. Again, without complete context it's impossible to say for sure. But even in a factory method, there are usually better ways to map the type parameter `T` to a specific implementation than using `if (typeof(T) == ...)`. It seems that all the generic aspect here is used for is casting, which seems like overkill, especially given the difficulty you run into doing casting in that context.

Comment: @PeterDuniho okay!  Back to the drawing board lol.

Comment: @DavidG you're right of course. Thank you.

Comment: Interestingly, the code compiles fine for me if I remove the `sealed` modifier from `UIDSerializer`.

Comment: @itsme86 And what are you `return` ing?

Comment: `return (IByteSerializer<T>)new UIDSerializer();`

Comment: @itsme86 I just tried that - it works!  Why would the `sealed` modifier have anything to do with that?

Comment: I'm not sure... If anything, you'd think `sealed` would have the opposite effect.

Comment: @PeterDuniho note edits and weird new information

Comment: Removing `sealed` opens the possibility to a derived type implementing the interface, even though the named type does not. Thus the explicit cast is allowed.

Comment: The reason it works wirhout sealed is you could make a derived class that accepts any value of T. It still will fail when someone does `SerializableObject<int>.GetTypeSerializer()` but now it fails at runtime instead of compile time.